# Override a function in SlickGrid JQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, overriding, slickgrid

I am working on the [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) Plugin.

I have made some changes in the file [slick.pager.js](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/controls/slick.pager.js) within the function `constructPagerUI();`. The `constructPagerUI()` function is called from the  function `SlickGridPager(dataView, grid, $container);` in the same file.

Now I am trying to move the modified function into a new JS plugin, which need to override the older one. How can I resolve this?